# How to write formula in Excel sheet which is stored in the perl variable

Tags: perl, excel

```
use strict
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my $Workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('cw.xls');
my $Worksheet = $Workbook->add_worksheet('MRD');

my $Formula= "A10+B10/2";
$Worksheet->write_formula(1,2,'='.($Formula));

exit;
```

Error getting:

```
Couldn't parse formula: =A10+B10/2;
```

Note : In the Formula that I am using contain across sheet data calling. 
When I am Pasting it in the excel sheet manually its working fine but through program I am unable to put it in the sheet.

Please if any one came across this problem or has solution let me know.

Comment: You need to see how the `Spreadsheet:WriteExcel` library operates; but at a guess - perhaps you shouldn't put the equals sign in front of it.

Comment: Aside from a missing semicolon after `strict`, this works fine on my machine.

Comment: Hi Adam Thanks for the reply actually I hav nt pasted my original code here because my expression stored in the formula variable is quite large. It is giving the Couldn't parse formula: error when I am running the same kind of code as I have pasted above.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the documentation of [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) module, it states in the [DIAGNOSTICS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#DIAGNOSTICS) section that:

**Couldn't parse formula ...**

There are a large number of warnings which relate to badly formed formulas and functions. See the "[FORMULAS AND FUNCTIONS IN EXCEL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#FORMULAS_AND_FUNCTIONS_IN_EXCEL)" section for suggestions on how to avoid these errors. You should also check the formula in Excel to ensure that it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem storing a formula in a variable and passing it to write_formula(). In fact your own snippet above proves that it works.

So the problem is with the formula that you are trying to write. Since you haven't posted the formula it is hard to guess what the problem might be but [here are some formula debugging tips from the docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#FORMULAS_AND_FUNCTIONS_IN_EXCEL):

1. Verify that the formula works in Excel (or Gnumeric or OpenOffice.org).
2. Ensure that it isn't on the Caveats list shown above. (In the docs).
3. Ensure that cell references and formula names are in uppercase.
4. Ensure that you are using ':' as the range operator, A1:A4.
5. Ensure that you are using ',' as the union operator, SUM(1,2,3).
6. Ensure that the function is in the above table. (In the docs).

P.S. The leading '=' isn't required when you are using write_formula() so you can just use:

```
$Worksheet->write_formula(1, 2, $Formula);
```

Comment: hi jmcnamara I know the above snippet is working and the formula that I have not pasted here that is also working in the excel sheet. I have also tried $Worksheet->write_formula(1, 2, $Formula);
Its giving same error that I have mentioned above.

Comment: Did you go through all of the items in the above checklist? If so post the formula that is causing the issue. That is the only way we will be able to help you.